# c# Sum to DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

Tags: c#

While Making a Game, I wanted to make a Cool Down Effect for an enemy that throws projectiles. 
I wanted to put the Time Of Day (Hours:Minutes:Seconds)in a variable (Like an Int or Something) and sum 10 seconds to the Time, and put this operation in an If.
Is there any way to do that?
Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: Can you give an example of input and desired output?

Comment: There are many ways to do that, read up on the Datetime and Timespan classes.

Comment: I would put Current time Date.Time.Now.TimeOfDay in some sort of Variable and to that number add 10 seconds, and i wanted to know how that could be done.

Comment: Linked duplicate explains how to do math on DateTime. If you question is "how to put result of method call in variable" I'm afraid it would not be answerable on SO due to amount of programming concepts explanations required to be put in the post.